# How to draw ROC of sensitivity and specificity?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc, auc

For specificity = 1 - FPR
I changed the code as follows：

```
plt.plot(1-fpr, tpr, 'b', label = 'AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
```

But the figure seems wrong.
[image]

This is what I see in paper.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your understanding about ROC curves. The ROC curve plots the true positive rate (sensitivity) `tpr = tp / (tp + fn)` agains the false positive rate (1 - specificity) `1 - (tn / (tn + fp)` at different thresholds. Now, I see that your title indicates that you want a 'ROC of sensitivity and specificity' but actually something like that does not exists. The way to address both sensitivity and specificity is via a ROC curve.

In order to get a ROC curve change the plot to:

`plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 'b', label = 'AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)`

You can see how to compute both the false positive rate and the true positive rate from the explanation above.

Then, when interpreting the ROC curve you want your classifiers to be positioned as close as possible to the top left corner indicating low false positive rate (high specificity) and high true positive rate (high sensitivity). With that said, the false positive rate doesn't represent the specificity, but the negative of the specificity instead. That is why you want it to be minimal.

Last but not least, the situation that can pretty often confuse people when it comes to ROC curves is when instead of having `1 - specificity` on the X axis there is `specificity`. When this happens, the direction of the values is reversed (as in the graph) so it goes from 1 to 0 instead of 0 to 1.

Comment: Please let me know if the edit helps you get a correct plot.

Comment: It works well, but I don't know can the false positive represent the specificity?

Comment: @Salmon I think that it should be clear enough now. In my latest edit I included the last bit of missing info. Let me know if the story is complete for you.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I think I'm a little clear that when I want to see the classifier's performance in sensitivity and specificity, I just need to draw a ROC curve. And the X-axis is always false positive rate instead of specifity.

Comment: I have this question because I see many ROC curves in papers draw with X-axis specificity and Y-axis sensitivity. I thought they changed the way of drawing ROC curve.

Comment: @Salmon that wouldn't make much sense. Anyways, if you think that my answer was sufficient I would appreciate if you mark it as correct. Otherwise feel free to let me know if you need any further explanation

Comment: okay, I add a figure in paper that confused me. Are you sure that its Specifity  just is false positive rate.

Comment: @Salmon Ok, another edit on my answer to cover your last comment.